# bash script crashes on variable assignment

Tags: bash, variables, variable-assignment

I'm writing a bash script to automate some opencv code which i need to run multiple times feeding in an array of variables.
For some reason though my bash script keeps crashing when i try and assign 0 to the flag variable.
I've also tried this outside the if loop and it also causes the script to crash.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Build most recent code
cd build2/
cmake ..
make

Scale=(9 9)

inputType="scale"

flag=1
counter=0
for i in ${Scale[@]}; do
    echo iteration: $counter

    if [ $counter -eq 0 ]
    then
      echo first iteration
      let flag=0 #Crashes Here
      echo after assignment $flag

    else
      echo not first iteration
      let flag=1 #Doesn't crash here
      echo after assignment $flag
    fi

    echo starting program
    #Note 1.inputValue  2.Input Type 3.firstGo
    ./multiDimen ${i} $inputType $flag

    echo Test Type is: $inputType
    let counter=counter+1
done
echo Done
```

Is there any reason why this should behave like this?

Comment: it would just exit, without any error message

Comment: after i replaced let with = though it started working fine, must have been improper use of let using it to assign a variable to 0 ??

Comment: This is one of [the caveats about `set -e`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking away the let and just use a plain '=' assignment, let is normally just for arithmetic, it's effectively the same as (()).

Answer (score 4):

With `set -e`, an arithmetic evaluation with a zero result is an "error" which you have to handle. Replacing the problematic `let` with a plain assignment removes the arithmetic context, so that's probably what you should do.

You should still review the rest of the script for similar issues, or forego the use of `set -e`, especially if you are not a Bash scripting expert. In particular, if the program you are testing could return a non-zero exit code, that would still terminate the script.

Comment: ah ok, this makes sense i might find another alternative to set -e

Answer (score 0):

**man set -e**
   Exit immediately if a simple command exits with a non-zero status, unless
   the command that fails is part of an until or  while loop, part of an
   if statement, part of a && or || list, or if the command's return status
   is being inverted using !.  -o errexit

**man let** Each expression is an arithmetic expression to be evaluated. If the last expression evaluates to 0, let returns 1; otherwise 0 is returned.

try remove set -e